# What is effective percentage?

Tags: percentages

I want to know more about concept of effective percentage. For example A sells to B at profit of 20 % and B sells to C at profit of 10 %. Then their effective profit percentage?

```
effective percentage = A + B + AB/100, i.e 20 + 10 + 200/100 = 32 %
```

I want to what is concept here and what exactly is profit percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to think about percentages is with multiplication rather than addition.

Suppose A sells an item that cost $X$ to B at at $20\%$ markup. Then B pays
$$
1.2 X 
$$
(the $1.2$ is the original $1$ plus the $20/100$ markup).
If B then sells to C at a $10\%$ markup then C pays
$$
1.1 \times 1.2X = 1.32X .
$$
That is why the combined markup is $32\%$, not $10\% + 20\% = 30\%$. The "extra" $2\%$ is because the second markup was applied to a larger, marked up cost.

If you multiply out
$$
(1 + 0.1)\times(1 + 0.2) = 1 +(0.1 + 0.2 + 0.1\times0.2)
$$
you can see the formula in the question.